# Matlab /Wait bar/ Progress bar/GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm trying to use the wait bar in a gui for a matlab program that recognises images. In simple words, a bounding box(rectangle) appears when there is a irregularity.
The bounding box doesnt appear when I  have the waitbar as normal or modal:

*f = waitbar(0,'Please wait...','WindowStyle','normal');*

But the bounding box appears when I use the following command

*f = waitbar(0,'Please wait...','WindowStyle','docked');*

I would want the wait bar to pop and not be docked. Any suggestions? 
Recommendations?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@ssroy, The bounding box(rectangle) is probably added to the figure of the waitbar instead of the figure where you want it. I would try to recall focus to that figure (or your GUI) when adding the bounding box, and follow it by refocussing on the waitbar afterwards.
In order to refocus on the waitbar , you can use again `f = waitbar(0,'Please wait...','WindowStyle','normal');` even if you don't change anything on it

Comment: You are right about the focus. When I try to refocus on to the GUI by adding this again "f = waitbar(0,'Please wait...','WindowStyle','normal');", multiple progress bars are created. If I use close(f), then its working but the waitbar flickers on the screen. If I use pause(f) to show the progress, then the run time is increasing. Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: Did you try using figure( f ) to keep the focus .

Comment: When using again "f = waitbar(0,'Please wait...','WindowStyle','normal');" should not create another progress bar. So I would try to understand why that is.

Comment: @Nico I believe using that command again would overwrite the existing progress bar.

Comment: @oro777 I tried using figure(f) as well. It still remains a mystery.

Comment: What about if you would declare your waitbar in the global workspace and not in the GUI workspace?